# Initialize Empty Class Array and populate from fetch Fetch function React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to populate a dropdown with values from API. I declared empty array in react class but cannot assign the values to it. I cannot use it as state variables as I have to make lot of changes to previously developed code. The way I did the code it says `options` is not defined.
The partial code is posted below which is causing the problem. Any help is really appreciated.

```
export default class LoadLimits extends Component {
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.options = []
    this.getZoneOptions = this.getZoneOptions.bind(this)
   }
   render(){
       return (
          <PtSelect label="Assigned Zone" options={options} 
                  onChange={this.onChangeDropdown} 
                    disabled={this.props.disabled}
                     defaultVal={this.state.assignedZone} name="assignedZone" />                        
     )
   }
   getZoneOptions =  () =>{
        const zoneOptions = []
        const keys = []
        fetch(`${config.server}/getzoneOptions/`+this.props.ownModel.agencyId)
        .then(response=>
            {
                return response.json();
            })
            
        .then(data=>{
            for (var i =0;i<data[0].length;i++){
                if (data[0][i]['Zone_key']!==998){
                zoneOptions.push(data[0][i]['description'])
                keys.push(data[0][i]['Zone_key'])
                }
            }
           let dropOptions = zoneOptions.map((option,idx)=>{
            return {key:keys[idx],value: option, label:option}
           });   
           this.options = dropOptions
       })
        
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log(error);
        });
    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `options` being passed to `PtSelect` is not defined.

```
<PtSelect
  label="Assigned Zone"
  options={options} // <-- should be this.options
  onChange={this.onChangeDropdown}
  disabled={this.props.disabled}
  defaultVal={this.state.assignedZone}
  name="assignedZone"
/>
```

## Solution

If you need a variable to hold a value that you don't want coupled to the React component lifecycle then you should probably use a [React ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs).

1. Import `createRef` from 'react'.
2. Create a mutable ref for the `options`.
3. Implement the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to populate and set the current value of the `options`.
4. Pass the current `options` value to the `PtSelect` component.

Code

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react';

class LoadLimits extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getZoneOptions = this.getZoneOptions.bind(this);

    this.options = createRef([]);
  }

  getZoneOptions = () => {
    const zoneOptions = [];
    const keys = [];
    fetch(`${config.server}/getzoneOptions/` + this.props.ownModel.agencyId)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })

      .then((data) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
          if (data[0][i]["Zone_key"] !== 998) {
            zoneOptions.push(data[0][i]["description"]);
            keys.push(data[0][i]["Zone_key"]);
          }
        }
        const dropOptions = zoneOptions.map((option, idx) => {
          return { key: keys[idx], value: option, label: option };
        });
        this.options.current = dropOptions;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getZoneOptions();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PtSelect
        label="Assigned Zone"
        options={this.options.current}
        onChange={this.onChangeDropdown}
        disabled={this.props.disabled}
        defaultVal={this.state.assignedZone}
        name="assignedZone"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

## Alternative Solution - Use `forceUpdate` (*not strongly suggested*)

In addition to addressing the `this.options` issue in `PtSelect`, you can use [forceUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) to tell React to rerender regardless of any state and/or prop update. This should rerender the select with populated options.

> ```
> component.forceUpdate(callback)
> ```
>
> By default, when your component’s state or props change, your
> component will re-render. If your `render()` method depends on some
> other data, you can tell React that the component needs re-rendering
> by calling `forceUpdate()`.
>
> Calling `forceUpdate()` will cause `render()` to be called on the
> component, skipping `shouldComponentUpdate()`. This will trigger the
> normal lifecycle methods for child components, including the
> `shouldComponentUpdate()` method of each child. React will still only
> update the DOM if the markup changes.
>
> Normally you should try to avoid all uses of `forceUpdate()` and only
> read from `this.props` and `this.state` in `render()`.

```
getZoneOptions = () => {
  const zoneOptions = [];
  const keys = [];
  fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })

    .then((data) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        zoneOptions.push(data[i]["name"]);
        keys.push(data[i]["id"]);
      }
      let dropOptions = zoneOptions.map((option, idx) => {
        return { key: keys[idx], value: option, label: option };
      });
      this.options = dropOptions;
      console.log("Options ", this.options);
      this.forceUpdate(); // <-- trigger a rerender
    })

    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: just curious can we also handle `{this.options ? <PtSelect />:<div/>}` or `{this options && <PtSelect/>}`

Comment: I just now figured out that I have missed the `this` keyword in the PtSelect. One more problem is going on. The dropdown is not loading as soon as the page loads. I have to click somewhere else in the component to load the dropdown. Any help with that? I did put the function in componentDidMount.

Comment: @techipank I assumed `PtSelect` could handle an empty array, but yes, you could conditionally render on `this.options.current.length` if using a React ref.

Comment: @SouradipRoy You could likely also call `this. getZoneOptions` as a callback (i.e. *some` `onClick` handler).

Comment: Also the `createRef([])` is showing TypeError. It says `__webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function`.

Comment: @DrewReese Alright. I will try to see if I can fix that because according to the functionality I dont know if I can find any onClick in that class.

Comment: @SouradipRoy Sorry, I didn't explicitly call it out, but you must import `createRef` from `react'. Oh, I thought you said you needed to click somewhere in the component to load the dropdown. Can you explain what you need to click on to trigger the loading?

Comment: @DrewReese I actually put the import function before you edited the answer but it is not solving the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231098/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-souradip-roy).

Comment: @DrewReese I have provided the sandbox code in the chat